# ESXi: Convert a pvscsi drive to a scsi drive

Tags: vmware, esxi, scsi, esx

I have a machine on my ESXi server that has a PVSCSI disk. I'd like to convert it to a SCSI disk. Is there a command line that does that?

Comment: Wrong site. This question has nothing to do with programming and is off topic.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Which site would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

This KB should walk you through the process: https://kb.vmware.com/kb/1002149